# How to hook into the Apple clock timer API in iPhone SDK 3.0?

Tags: iphone, timer, clock

I have heard that there are some apps that hook into the Apple processes that will run in the background (namely, hooking into the Apple clock timer API), which will allow some non-UI background process on your 3rd party app to continue to run. Is this legitimate? Supposedly, there are some GPS-tracker apps that are using this and have passed Apple review and are for sale in the app store.Can I  realize this and how can I do?Is there any API for this?

Any ideas?Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no public API to do this. ALso, as far as I know some of these Alarm Clock Apps do not use a private API. They are simply apps that need to be be running all the time.

Comment: Is there any method to implement this?Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Even if there is a way, you will not get through the AppStore review process. They now use an automated search for private API calls and automatically reject any apps that they find to be using private APIs. Further, you are not allowed to run your app in the background, if they discover that you have managed to do this, your app will be rejected.

Comment: If I use private API,how can I implement this ?Any ideas?

Comment: Nope, I don't know of one. You could write your app for jailbroken iPhones and tell people to enable it to run in the background.

Comment: Cocos2d is a private api? Many gamers developers are using it. Why this apps don't get rejected? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Private meaning Apple's undisclosed API, and private as in 3rd party. Cocos2d is fine to use.